# AWS CDK Python - Resuse a block of code from a config.py file in other project stack files

Tags: python, aws-cdk

I am trying to use the **config.py** file to contain code for resource tags that I want to execute in the other **project stack files**.  This way the config.py file will be the only location where the tagging information will need to be updated when changes are necessary.  I am still learning Python so any assistance on this would be greatly appreciated.

**In config.py**

```py
from aws_cdk import core

class ResourceTags():
    
    def __init__(self):
        core.Tags.of(self).add("createdPurpose", "value")
        core.Tags.of(self).add("createdBy", "value")
        core.Tags.of(self).add("project", "value")
        core.Tags.of(self).add("stackName", self.stack_name)
```

**In stack.py file(s)**

```py
from config import ResourceTags
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have a helper class with a method that takes in an instance of a class that implements the Stack class. In your example you are trying to apply tags to a class that does not implement the "Stack" class. You need to pass in something that does.

Here is a quick C# example

```
    class ResourceTags
    {
        private void ApplyTags(Construct scope)
        {
            Tags.Of(scope).Add("Tag1", "Val1");
            Tags.Of(scope).Add("Tag1", "Val1");
            Tags.Of(scope).Add("Tag1", "Val1");
            
        }

        public void ApplyTags(Construct scope)
        {
            this.ApplyTags(scope);
        }
    }


    class MyStack : Stack
    {
        internal MyStack()
        {


            new ResourceTags().ApplyTags(this);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up with.  I'm definitely willing to accept any better ideas.
I am still very new to the object orientated aspects.  Thanks to all who participated.

**In config.py**

```py
from aws_cdk import core

class Config(object):
    '''Configuration options for the different stacks
    '''

    def ResourceTags(self):

        core.Tags.of(self).add("createdPurpose", "value")
        core.Tags.of(self).add("createdBy", "value")
        core.Tags.of(self).add("project", "value")
        core.Tags.of(self).add("stackName", self.stack_name)
```

**In stack.py**

```py
from config import Config

...Other stack code

        # To add tags from config.py
        Config.ResourceTags(self)
```